# How to auto enable the plugin during installation in Joomla?

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-extensions

Does any good way in Joomla to auto enable the plugin during installation? I have followed the [post topics](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=2378218) but do not get any straight forward solution.

I have used below code during installation for auto enabling the plugin :

```
UPDATE `#__extensions` SET `enabled` = 1 WHERE `element` = 'plugin_name';
```

But I want to know better solution.

/Thanks

Comment: I dont know any day when my plugs were not auto enabled during installation or reinstallation. Are u sure you need to do this manually?

Comment: @Flextra yes. It not need any additional configuration so it can be enabled automatically.

Comment: Can you please add your full code that you used for your database query. Also are you adding this code to an install.php file inside a function?

Answer (score 5):

That's the only way only way I'm aware of; detailed below for others who might stumble on this trying to figure out how to do it.

Add scripfile to the manifest (XML), below the `</description>` tag:

```
<scriptfile>my_script.php</scriptfile>
```

my_script.php:

```
class PlgSystemPluginnameInstallerScript
{
 public function install($parent)
 {
  // Enable plugin
  $db  = JFactory::getDbo();
  $query = $db->getQuery(true);
  $query->update('#__extensions');
  $query->set($db->quoteName('enabled') . ' = 1');
  $query->where($db->quoteName('element') . ' = ' . $db->quote('PLUGIN_NAME_GOES_HERE'));
  $query->where($db->quoteName('type') . ' = ' . $db->quote('plugin'));
  $db->setQuery($query);
  $db->execute();
 }
}
```

Tip: If it's a content plugin, replace `PlgSystemPluginnameInstallerScript` with `PlgContentPluginnameInstallerScript`.